# How to make the nth root of a product act the same as simple multiplication in regard to parity?

Tags: notation, roots, radicals

I don't have any experience working with radicals, but I'm working on a function that requires products of nth roots to be positive or negative, depending on the number of negative factors.

*I've done some initial research, and reviews these Stack questions: [Square roots — positive and negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative) and [The Product Rule of Square Roots with Negative Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437908/the-product-rule-of-square-roots-with-negative-numbers) but I couldn't find the information I was seeking (or am not fully understanding the answers.)*

Are the following expressions true?  If not, how can I produce the those results?

$\sqrt[2]{1*-1} = -1$

$\sqrt[3]{1*1*-1} = -1$

$\sqrt[3]{1*-1*-1} = 1$

---

[update] This is what the function does:

$\sqrt[n]{\overline{\Delta_1}*\overline{\Delta_2} *...*\overline{\Delta_n}}  \text{   }*\text{ } 
 \frac{\overline{\Delta_1}*\overline{\Delta_2} *...*\overline{\Delta_n}}{\Delta_1*\Delta_2*...*\Delta_n}$

such that if there are an odd number of negative factors, the product is negative, otherwise positive.

- Is there a more compact way to express this?

also, any tips on notation are appreciated.

Comment: $\sqrt{-1} =i$, so the first statement is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

- $\sqrt[2]{1\times(-1)} = \sqrt{-1} \neq -1\quad \color{red}\checkmark$ indeed $-1\times -1=1$
- $\sqrt[3]{1\times1\times(-1)} = \sqrt[3]{-1} = -1\quad \color{green}\checkmark$ indeed $-1\times -1\times -1=-1$
- $\sqrt[3]{1\times(-1)\times(-1)} = \sqrt[3]{1}=1\quad \color{green}\checkmark$ indeed $1\times 1\times 1=1$

As a general rule

- for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ even and $a\ge 0$ we have

$$\sqrt[n] a=b \iff b\ge 0 \quad b^n=a$$

- for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ odd and we have

$$\sqrt[n] a=b \iff b^n=a$$

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the method you want.

We have Euler's formula
$$e^{i\theta} = i\sin\theta+\cos\theta$$
We can take  $n^{th}$ root of both sides to obtain
$$\sqrt[n]{e^{i\theta}}=\sqrt[n]{i\sin\theta+\cos\theta}\tag{1}$$

It seems like you are only asking for the cases for $1$ and $-1$, so let's do the following.

It is clear that $\sqrt[n]{1}$ is $1$ or $-1$ regardless of whether $n$ is odd or even. The problem is how to figure out $\sqrt[n]{-1}$. For $n$ is odd, $\sqrt[n]{-1}=-1$.

For $n$ is even, let's suppose $\theta = \pi$. Then, from $(1)$ we have
$$\sqrt[n]{e^{i\pi}}= \sqrt[n]{-1}$$
$$e^{i\frac{\pi}{n}} = \sqrt[n]{-1}$$
$$\sqrt[n]{-1}= i\sin\frac{\pi}{n}+\cos\frac{\pi}{n}$$
I apologize if this is not what you are looking for.